# Nginx as Reverse Proxy - Double Proxy Pass ? is this possible?

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, jetty, openfire

I have common problem anyone can encounter when you run nginx as a reverse proxy server for apache, i want to add double proxy_pass variables to the nginx conf. file but this doesn't seems to be allowed by nginx.

For example situations i have is 
In my website i have chat engine runs by openfire, which runs on port 5280 with Jetty and i have set the apache proxy pass directive set as

```
ProxyPass /member-chat http://xyx.com:5280/http-bind
ProxyPassreverse /member-chat http://xyx.com:5280/http-bind
ProxyRequests Off
```

but i want to pass anything that comes to the "/member-chat" send directly to the chat-server rather than the apache, because then what apache would do is again proxy pass that to the openfire (member-chat), which takes more time and useless loading for apache.

when i add the nginx as the proxy server i want to add like this below but this didn't work, for some reason, it cant find the location gives me 404 error.

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://85.xxx.yyy.2x2:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log off;
    }

   location ~ ^/member-chat {
       proxy_pass http://85.xxx.yyy.2x2:5280;
       proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you missed out on specifying the URI for the Jetty service. With your current configuration, the request that will land up on Jetty port would be:

```
http://85.xxx.yyy.2x2:5280/member-chat
```

This is as per the [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) documentation.

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI

I don't think that is what you expect looking at your Apache configuration for the same. Try configuring the URI for proxy_pass directive as you have done for Apache.

```
location ~ ^/member-chat {
   proxy_pass http://85.xxx.yyy.2x2:5280/http-bind;
   proxy_connect_timeout 300;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i still get "nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or ,,,etc"

Comment: This seems like a limitation of the proxy_pass directive. I missed it out. Is it really a requirement for you to use a REGEX in location member-chat? Consider using "location /member-chat", which will match any request with a prefix URI as "/member-chat".